# Is there a WebGoat like Java application to practice profiling?

Tags: java, profiling

Is there a WebGoat like Java application to practice Java profiling ?

[WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project) is a deliberately insecure Java EE web application to teach and understand web security. Is there anything like that for profiling ?

I guess I am looking for a Java web application that is deliberately memory leaking, memory hogging (for certain use cases), sometimes CPU hogging, and at times thread racing. When I use 'at times' I mean in certain well known use cases, so we can simulate the behavior.